# Find a linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^4$ such that:

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Find a linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^4$ such that: $$Ker(T) = \langle (1, 0, 1, 0), (-1, 0, 0, 1) \rangle$$ $$\text{and}$$ $$Im(T) = \langle (1, -1, 0, 2) , (0, 1, -1, 0) \rangle .$$

I'm not sure if I understand the exercise correctly, does the linear transformation for $Ker$ and $Im$ need to be the same?

I could only think of transformation to $Im$ is that correct?

$T(1,0,0,0) = (1,-1,0,2); T(0,1,0,0) = (1,-1,0,2)$

$T(0,0,1,0) = (0,-1,1,0); T(0,0,0,1) = (0,-1,1,0)$

{$T(1,0,0,0),T(0,1,0,0),T(0,0,1,0),T(0,0,0,1)$} = {$(1,-1,0,2), (0,-1,1,0)$}.

Regarding $Ker$ I need to find a linear transformation that takes the range of {$(1,-1,0,2),(0,-1,1,0)$} which are equal to 0? right? Could it be {$T(0,0,0,0),T(0,0,0,0),T(0,0,0,0),T(0,0,0,0)$} ?

But then there would be no answer because the transformations are different. So I'm stuck. Any help will be most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: these 4 vectors form a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need *one* linear transformation.   The hint is a good one.  Specifying what a linear transformation does to a basis uniquely determines it.

Check that the four vectors mentioned are linearly independent,  and hence form a basis.

We know we need $T(1,0,1,0)=T(-1,0,0,1)=0$.

Now we are free to define $T(1,-1,0,2)=(1,-1,0,2)$ and $T(0,-1,1,0)=(0,-1,1,0)$, thus fulfilling the requirements.

(This is one of the easiest ways to lick this one.)